# Get the selected text-field% in a Racket GUI

Tags: user-interface, scheme, racket

I have an application that uses the [The Racket Graphical Interface Toolkit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/) to create a GUI.
I also have a frame with several fields, that is created with the code below:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

(define frame (new frame% [label "frame"]))
(define field-1 (new text-field% [label "field-1"] [parent frame])) ;; add field to frame
(define field-2 (new text-field% [label "field-2"] [parent frame]))
(define field-3 (new text-field% [label "field-3"] [parent frame]))

(send frame show #t) ;; show the frame
```

Is there a way that I can dynamically determine the selected field ? Thus, asking the selected field to the frame and retrieve a reference to that field if it is selected.

Answer (score 3):

`text-field%` implements the `window<%>` interface so you could use [`on-focus`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html?q=on-focus#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred/main..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._on-focus%29%29) directly:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

(define my-text-field%
  (class text-field%
    (super-new)
    (define/override (on-focus on?)
      (when on? (printf "~a\n" (send this get-label))))))

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"]))
(define field-1 (new my-text-field% [label "field-1"] [parent frame]))
(define field-2 (new my-text-field% [label "field-2"] [parent frame]))
(define field-3 (new my-text-field% [label "field-3"] [parent frame]))

(send frame show #t) ;; show the frame
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution, but it seems to be a dirty one.

I extend the `frame%` class so I can catch the `on-subwindow-focus` events. While catching these events, I check if it is a focus (and not an unfocus) and if the `object-name` of the receiver is a `text-field%`, the focus can be registered.

The code that implements the example:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

(define my-frame%
  (class frame%
    (super-new)
    (define/override (on-subwindow-focus r e)
      (when (and e (eq? 'object:text-field% (object-name r)))
        (printf "selected ~a~n" (send r get-label))))))

(define frame (new my-frame% [label "Frame"]))
(define field-1 (new text-field% [label "field-1"] [parent frame])) ;; add field to frame
(define field-2 (new text-field% [label "field-2"] [parent frame]))
(define field-3 (new text-field% [label "field-3"] [parent frame]))

(send frame show #t) ;; show the frame
```